# Inconsistent Generate Change Script

Tags: sql-server-2005, scripting

I add a column of type tinyint and being set to not allow nulls in a table and generate the change scripts.  The table has data in it at this time.  The script has code that creates a temp table and inserts the data that is in the current table into.  It then deletes the old table and renames this temp table to the same name as the original table.  All fine and good.  My question is, why if I do the same thing to another table (same field, but different table), the generate change script does not include this new table insertion code?

Any tips would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the table does not contain data, there is no need to rebuild the table.  Essentially Management Studio "plays it safe" behind the scenes by generating the script this way if it thinks it can't do it simply by just modifying the table.  In my experience, it often does this when it doesn't really need to, however there are exceptions ... for example if you add your column *not* at the "end" of the table.  Rather than make changes in the UI and script them, I recommend becoming familiar with the ALTER TABLE command.  Rebuilding the table in that manner can be catastrophic on a production system, and can usually be avoided.